# Conversion error due to mismatch data types

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When I execute this

```
UPDATE #Export 
SET LANID = SubString(DBF.LANID,1,10),New_LANID = DBF.LANID          
FROM #Export SE      
Left JOIN tbl_PERSON_BLUE_ALL_VW_SOAtoOracle DBF 
ON 
Convert(Int,DBF.persn_Id)=SE.emp_id
```

I get this error

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 159
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '000G76007' to data type int.
```

Modifying the JOIN seems to fix it.

```
UPDATE #Export 
SET LANID = SubString(DBF.LANID,1,10),New_LANID = DBF.LANID          
FROM #Export SE      
Left JOIN tbl_PERSON_BLUE_ALL_VW_SOAtoOracle DBF 
ON 
TRY_CAST(DBF.persn_Id as int) IS NOT NULL AND
Convert(Int,DBF.persn_Id)=SE.emp_id
```

Is there still a possibility that this may fail?  Is there a better fix?

Comment: The text value `000G76007` will never be convertible to an integer, ever.  So either you are casting the wrong column, or you are going to have to go into your table and remove non integer text values.

Comment: You only have 2 places this could be. `CONVERT(int,DBF.persn_Id)` or `SE.emp_id`. One of those columns has values that aren't integers and you're trying to convert it to an `int`. Why are you trying to compare an `int` to a `varchar` anyway though?

Comment: The try_cast in your join will cause the non-integer rows (like '000G76007') to be dropped. However, that does not resolve the fundamental issue. As others have asked, why are you trying to compare a column that clearly can contain alpha values to an integer column?

Comment: Because when the PERSON ID is numeric, the LAN ID is useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `try_convert()`!

```
UPDATE SE
    SET LANID = LEFT(DBF.LANID, 10),
        New_LANID = DBF.LANID          
    FROM #Export SE LEFT JOIN   
        tbl_PERSON_BLUE_ALL_VW_SOAtoOracle DBF 
        ON TRY_CONVERT(INT, DBF.persn_Id) = SE.emp_id ;
```

Notes:

- `TRY_CONVERT()` will eliminate the conversion errors.  By converting to an int, you also eliminate problems with leading zeros.
- The two ids should be of the same type!  You can't even declare a proper foreign key relationship.
- `LEFT()` is more convenient than `SUBSTRING()` in this case.
- Use the table alias defined in the `FROM` clause.  I actually consider it a bug in SQL Server that you can directly reference the table even though it has a table alias.

Comment: Thanks. That's cleaner as long as it still always will work, which i expect it will. I know that sometimes parallelism's impact on when operations are perform can cause occasional "random" errors

Comment: @ChadD . . . It might be the parallel environment.  It is more likely the optimizer.  Some execution plans might attempt the conversion even when other filters would filter out the row.